# preg_match_all for nested element

Tags: php, preg-match-all

This is a kind of BB codes. Any idea how to match all elements like [LI]text[/LI] and [UL]text[/UL]?

```
preg_match_all("/(\[UL].*\[\/UL])|(\[LI].*\[\/LI])/", '[UL][LI]sadas[/LI][/UL]', $match);
```

Want to receive something like:

```
0 => "[UL][LI]sadas[/LI][/UL]"
1 => "[UL][LI]sadas[/LI][/UL]"
2 => "[LI]sadas[/LI]"    <--- This is not captured now.
```

Basically it is about: How to get this [LI]text[/LI] part and not loose [UL]text[/UL] part?

Comment: First part of condition (`[UL]`) is matched, there is no reason to match the second one too (nested `[LI]`)

Comment: It won't return overlapping matches.

Comment: `preg_match_all("~(\[UL](.*?)\[/UL]~s", '[UL][LI]sadas[/LI][/UL]', $match);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need 2 things:

- a recursive subpattern (a subpattern in a capture group that refers to itself)
- to put this recursive pattern inside a lookahead assertion (because an assertion doesn't consume characters, and, with this trick, you can match several times the same substrings)

`~(?=(\[(\w+)]([^[]*(?:(?1)[^[]*)*?)\[/\2]))~`

`(?=...)` is the lookahead assertion. (the current position is followed by ...)
`(\[(\w+)]([^[]*(?:(?1)[^[]*)*?)\[/\2])` is the capture group 1.
`(?1)` refers to the subpattern inside the capture group 1.
`\2` refers to the match of the capture group 2 (the tag name).

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AU0NEO/1)

Comment: While that was not exactly solving my problem, I used that to create what I've needed. I wouldn't find that out without your help so I am accepting this answear. Thanks!